# How do I link a static GLEW library to a CMake project using MinGW?

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, linker, glew

I'm trying to make a simple triangle project to learn OpenGL, but I'm stuck at a compile error:

```cpp
GLFWwindow* initApp() {

  if (!glfwInit()) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW context" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }

  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 4);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
  glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

  GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "TriangleApp", nullptr, nullptr);
  if (window == nullptr) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return nullptr;
  }

  glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
  glewExperimental = true;
  if (!glewInit()) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GL libraries" << std::endl;
    return nullptr;
  }

  return window;
}
```

CMake is telling me there's an undefined reference to `glewInit` and `glewExperimental`. I have included `glew.h` before any OpenGL header, defined `GLEW_STATIC` in my CMake project and linked `glfw3.a` and `glew32s.lib` to the target using `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)

project(TriangleApp)

# GLEW
add_compile_definitions(GLEW_STATIC)
include_directories(libraries/glew/include)
set(GLEW_LINK_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/glew/lib/Release/Win32/glew32s.lib)

# GLFW
include_directories(libraries/glfw/include)
set(GLFW_LINK_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libraries/glfw/lib/libglfw3.a)

# My App
include_directories(headers)
add_executable(TriangleApp source/Main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TriangleApp
  ${GLEW_LINK_LIBRARY}
  ${GLFW_LINK_LIBRARY})
```

Here's the output from the CMake Tasks extension (vscode):

```
[main] Building folder: TriangleApp 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/benjo/source/repos/windows/C++/OpenGL/TriangleApp/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] Scanning dependencies of target TriangleApp
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TriangleApp.dir/source/Main.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable TriangleApp.exe
[build] CMakeFiles\TriangleApp.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj): In function `initApp()':
[build] C:/Users/benjo/source/repos/windows/C++/OpenGL/TriangleApp/source/Main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `glewInit'
[build] CMakeFiles\TriangleApp.dir/objects.a(Main.cpp.obj):Main.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr.glewExperimental[.refptr.glewExperimental]+0x0): undefined reference to `glewExperimental'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\TriangleApp.dir\build.make:108: TriangleApp.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/TriangleApp.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: Can you add the console output of CMake with the errors to your post? That would be helpful.

Comment: Yep, done that now @vre

Comment: @drescherjm Hi how so? For clarity it's just setting a variable so it's included in target_link_libraries at the bottom

Comment: @drescherjm GLEW provide a .lib file for windows static libraries, GLFW provided a .a file, I don't think there's a difference between the two but changing .lib to .a causes a library not found error

Comment: @drescherjm No actually the site you linked might be useful. It does say it should be used with VC++ not MinGW, I'll try linking dynamically or adding the `-DGLEW_STATIC` compile flag as it suggests

Comment: [https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Windows#GLEW](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Windows#GLEW) says the windows binaries will not work for linking statically but you can link dynamically to the dll.  At the bottom it says ***or, you can build GLEW statically: add glew32s.lib to linker libraries in the linker options, and add -DGLEW_STATIC to your compiler flags.*** I expect that means use CMake to build glew32s.lib using mingw.

Comment: @drescherjm `add_compile_definitions(GLEW_STATIC)` is the same as adding `-DGLEW_STATIC` as a compiler flag, so it's not working. I wanted to avoid dynamic linking but it may be my only option

Comment: I think you are doing that to your `TriangleApp` and not building glew from source. Correct? I believe the insructions are about building glew from source code (although they could be improved).

Comment: Possibly related: [https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/223](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew/issues/223)

Comment: @drescherjm that gave me a platform not supported error weirdly